# Closed Cover of [0,1] with no finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis

My question is:
Construct a cover of the Segment $[0 \le x \le 1]$ by closed subsets which does not have any finite subcover

So, we need to find a system $\mu$ of sets $G_{\alpha}$ such that their union $\bigcup_{\alpha} G_{\alpha} = [0,1]$ and there doesn't exist a subset of $\mu$ that covers $[0,1]$? Will a sequence such as $$[{ 1 \over 2},{1 \over 2}] \cup [{1\over3},{2\over3}]\cup [{1\over4},{3\over4}]\cup [{1\over5},{4\over5}]\cup  ...$$
work as a cover? In the limit we are approaching $[0,1]$ and no subset of this covers $[0,1]$.

Comment: Neither $0$ nor $1$ is covered, so this is not a cover of $[0,1]$.  Hint: points are closed.

Comment: So I can just add the sets $[0]$ and $[1]$ into the union?

Comment: It wasn't what I was thinking, but that would work.  I was thinking of $\{\{x\}|0\leq x\leq1\}$.

Comment: But then isn't $[0,1]$ a subset of your set that covers $[0,1]$ so that a finite subcover does exist?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  $[0,1]$ is not an element of the cover.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. My misunderstanding was that in your cover the sets ${x}$ are all points in $[0,1]$ but not the intervals themselves.